# Hokuyo Node Frame ID problem for Slam

Tags: slam, navigation, laser, hokuyo, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to do slam with hector_mapping. I have setted up all the necessary steps. All the transforms have been made. But when I run the rviz it seems there is no transform between base_link and laser. But actually it is published with static transform publisher and I confirmed that with tf_monitor.

When I run tf_monitor for base_link and laser, under laser it says "NO PARENT". These brings to my mind if there is problem with hokuyo_node. When I look at it, it seems ok and frame_id is setted to laser.

I really get confused with that. Any helps appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61729/hokuyo-node-frame-id-problem-for-slam/) by [cheour](https://answers.ros.org/users/2230/cheour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-04-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-04-29**:
Can you post the commandline or parameters you are using for your static transform publisher? Also you could post your tf tree from `rosrun tf view_frames`.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-10-28**:
check out   http://answers.ros.org/question/92026/static-latch-frames-not-shown-in-tf-frame-graph/ looks related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when you run hector_slam without odom,your view_frame like this /map -> /base_link  this is publish by hector-slam,then /base_link -> /laser publish by static-transform.and I don't really get your problem,could you provide detail？

---

Originally posted by [bailiqun](https://answers.ros.org/users/25687/bailiqun/) with karma: 16 on 2016-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0